# EJB converter and lost bean injection

Tags: jsf, ejb, converters

I have an application written in Java EE with EJB and JSF. I wanted to create a JSF converter which has an EJB injected:

```
@ManagedBean(name="addressConverter")
@RequestScoped
public class AddressConverter implements Converter {

    @EJB(name = "AddressDao")
    private AddressDao addressDao;

    @Override
    public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, String value) {
        return addressDao.find(Long.valueOf(value));
    }

    @Override
    public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) {
        return String.valueOf(((Address) value).getId());
    }
}
```

When in application any exception appears, the injected `AddressDao` is missing and I get the meeste that "...env.../AddressDao" is missing (sorry, I can't get the exact error right now).

How do I handle that?

Comment: You want to know why it's happening or how to trap the exception?

Comment: i would like to know why its happening.. but catching an error would be a nice start.